# Calculate camera target

Tags: camera, projection-matrix

[image]How calculate camera target position, if I have front/back planes, camera transformation matrix and camera lens length?

Comment: I mean a point of camera target (x,y,z). Look on the picture.

Comment: What do you mean by "target position"? Intersection of forward vector with far plane?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

This is assuming that you have used the following function

```
void gluLookAt(GLdouble eyeX,
  GLdouble eyeY,
  GLdouble eyeZ,
  GLdouble centerX,
  GLdouble centerY,
  GLdouble centerZ,
  GLdouble upX,
  GLdouble upY,
  GLdouble upZ);
```

to get your transformation matrix, and that you want to find what values were used for `center` parameters.

The lookat method will give you a matrix that is good to transform the camera position, but will use 'clean' values for it: it will at least normalize the center-eye vector.

If you want to keep track of what is the 'center' of the camera, keep it in a variable, and use that variable instead.

([Doc](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml))